# Getting value from dataframe based on Series with column name

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a DataFrame with date indexes and column names.

```
df1 = 
date       col1  col2  col3
20190101   1     2     3
20190102   6     5     4
20190103   -7    -9    -8
20190104   4     9     8
```

and then I have Series with a subset of the indexes and a column name with the name of the column with the highest value above 0 for each row. Like this.

```
max_col = 
20190101   col3
20190102   col1
20190104   col2
```

I would like a result with the value of the column names in max_col.

```
max_val = 
20190101   3
20190102   6
20190104   9
```

I have tried with `df1.loc[max_col]`, `df1.at[max_col]` but the closest being `df1[max_col]`. But this creates a matrix instead of vector response.

Any ideas?

EDIT:

The values in `max_col` comes from another DataFrame `df2`. 
So the `max_val` does not have to be the max values from df1. My mistake.

The solution with `df1.lookup(max_col.index, max_col)` worked great.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your initial df, just use `df.max(1)`. Then, filter out all values that are negative.

```
s = df.max(1)
s[s>0]
```

returns

```
date
20190101    3
20190102    6
20190104    9
dtype: int64
```

---

But if you really want to use your `max_col` series, you are looking at the definition of [`df.lookup`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.lookup.html)

```
df.lookup(max_col.index, max_col)
```

Comment: Great, thanks. The lookup is what I needed. I also realized that I made an error in the question. The max_col series with column names comes from another DataFrame df2 and has the name of the columns with the highest values in df2. Sorry about that.